# unexpected cast to boolean?

Tags: php, syntax, php-5.3

Given this input: http://example.com/item.php?room=248&supply_id=18823, the following 2 blocks ought to produce the same result. Why don't they? What am I missing other than coffee?

This block gives the expected values:

```
if (isset($_GET['supply_id']) && isset($_GET['room'])) {
    $id=validkey($_GET['supply_id']); //18823
    $room=validkey($_GET['room']); //248
    $arr=array('s'=>$id,'r'=>$room); //s=>18823, r=>248
}
```

But if I do the check and the assignment in one step, $id ends up equal to 1 instead of 18823. Why?

```
if (isset($_GET['supply_id']) && isset($_GET['room'])) {
    if($id=validkey($_GET['supply_id']) && $room=validkey($_GET['room'])) 
        $arr=array('s'=>$id",'r'=>$room); //s=>1, r=>248
}
```

This is the function I'm using:

```
function validkey($value){
    if(is_scalar($value)){
        $value=(int)$value;
        return ($value>0) ? $value : false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use parentheses:

```
if(($id=validkey($_GET['supply_id'])) && ($room=validkey($_GET['room'])))
```

Otherwise the result of `validkey($_GET['supply_id']) && $room=validkey($_GET['room'])` is assigned to `$id` variable because `&&` operator has higher precedence than `=`

Comment: This is the answer. I've run into this problem before and it's really confusing the first time you encounter it - `&&` has a higher precedence than `=`. So you have to wrap the assignment in an extra set of parentheses.

Comment: However I think this sort of syntax is generally a bad idea - it makes code harder to follow, and is more open to errors creeping in.

Comment: Yup, or use `AND` which i don't like ;)

Comment: Use it sparingly. I've occasionally done something like `if (($aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rQuery)) && $aRow['foo'] == true)`, but having array dereferencing someday will negate the need for that.

Answer (score 3):

The `&&` operator binds stronger than the `=` operator.

So your code basically becomes `if ($id = (validkey($_GET['supply_id']) && $room = validkey($_GET['room'])))`

--> Add parenthesis around the `$foo = $bar` expressions in your IF statement.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a small error in your second example - a stray doubble quote after $id. Also, your second approach is generally frowned upon (assigning variables in an if construct) as it makes code considerably harder to follow. Clearer would be the following:

```
if (isset($_GET['supply_id']) && isset($_GET['room'])) {     
    $id=validkey($_GET['supply_id']); //18823     
    $room=validkey($_GET['room']); //248

    if($id && $room) {     
        $arr=array('s'=>$id,'r'=>$room); //s=>18823, r=>248 
    }
}
```

Comment: the extra quote was a typo. I've fixed it. I can see where doing the assignment and checking for truth would be clearer if done in 2 steps, but I don't think I would call `validkey` twice.  The internal `if` need only by `if($id && $room){}`

Comment: You're quite right, I just hadn't read the code snippet I cut and pasted from :) I've updated my answer.