# php variable assignment inside if conditional

Tags: php, if-statement

The following two `if`s produced different results(first `if` echos hi, second does not), why?  why didn't the variable assignment on `$t` work?  is this due to `$t`'s local scope inside the `if` conditional?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["test"]) && $t=trim($_REQUEST["test"]) && !empty($t)){
   echo 'hi'
}

if(isset($_REQUEST["test"]) && $t=trim($_REQUEST["test"])){
   if(!empty($t))echo 'hi'
}
```

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091986/unexpected-cast-to-boolean/5092026#5092026)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`&&` has a [higher precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `=`, hence the first expression is evaluated as:

```
isset($_REQUEST['test']) && $t = (trim($_REQUEST['test']) && !empty($t))
```

Since `!empty($t)` is evaluated before anything is assigned to `$t`, the expression is `false`. You could fix this by explicitly setting parentheses, or by using a less awkward way to write it:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['test']) && trim($_REQUEST['test'])) {
    echo 'hi';
}
```

`trim($_REQUEST['test'])` will evaluate to `true` or `false` just by itself, no `empty` necessary. If you actually need the `trim`med value later, you can save it like so:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['test']) && ($t = trim($_REQUEST['test']))) {
    echo 'hi';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make minor modification like this in your code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["test"]) && ($t=trim($_REQUEST["test"])) && !empty($t)){
   echo '1: hi<br/>';
}

if(isset($_REQUEST["test"]) && $t=trim($_REQUEST["test"])){
   if(!empty($t))
      echo '2: hi<br/>';
}
```

Then both `1: hi` and `2: hi` will be printed. Difference is parenthesis around first $t assignment.