# Assignment in conditional, why it's not working?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

This simple conditional assignment (yes, unfortunately i like it!) is not working. What's the scope of `$x` and `$i` variables?

```
if($x = $s->getXAxis() && ($i = array_search($x, $this->xAxis)) !== false) // 88
   $s->xAxis = $i;                                                         // 89
```

I got:

> Notice: Undefined variable: x on line 88.

Comment: The same question is answered in more depth here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467151/php-variable-assignment-inside-if-conditional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it is operator precedence, try putting assignment into parenthesis:

```
if(($x = $s->getXAxis()) && ($i = array_search($x, $this->xAxis)) !== false)
   $s->xAxis = $i;
```

Comment: Might be right on precedence, but there's really no reason to glob the set of X into the conditional in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Is the first expression supposed to assign a value to `$x`? 
Check that `$x` is defined: `isset($x)`